# Why am I getting a dependencies not found error in vue.js when I create a new component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So in a vanilla vue.js skeleton project, there is a component called HelloWorld.

views/Home.vue is importing this component

```
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

Again this is all in the skeleton project, I didn't change anything.

If I take this example and change HelloWorld to Hello (while also changing all references inside of views/Home.vue to Hello.  I get the following error:

```
* @/components/Hello.vue in ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--12-0!../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

What am I missing here?

When I grep the project directory I am finding references to Hello World in node_modules directory, not sure what that is about

Comment: Do you get the dependency error before or after changing it to Hello.vue?

Comment: only after changing name

Comment: To install them, you can run: npm install --save @/components/Hello.vue

Comment: thats part of the error

Comment: Is there any way you can get the project up on GitHub? Sounds like there is a reference to HelloWorld.vue that isn't being changed to Hello.vue (or its variable representation).

Comment: I did a grep of my project directory and I keep seeing references to HelloWorld inside the node directory.  For example node_modules/@vue/cli-service/generator/template/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Why is it being referenced in the node modules directory?

Comment: Sounds like you used `vue cli` to create the project.

Comment: I did, I didn't know there was any other way except the CLI and the GUI

Comment: I don't understand why the vue components are being referenced in node_modules directory

Comment: Thats not a bad thing.. `vue cli` is good.. I guess that is where they store the template? Idk... You wouldn't happen to be using `vue router` would you?

Comment: My guess is they use it to copy over as the "vanilla starter project" when you create a new vue app from the cli.

Comment: The error is indicating that it can't find the file `@/components/Hello.vue`. Did you change the filename as well? `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/generator/template/src/components/HelloWorld.vue` is just a template, and is not actually being referenced in your project. That file is unrelated to the error.

Comment: changing @ /components to ../components in the import statement seems to work

Comment: no idea why @ would throw those errors though, since I think @ just points to my /src directory